# Error installing remote VS code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I constantly use MS VS code for remote development and it is overall a great IDE. But I noticed that extensions that I use all the time ([python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and [juypyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)) stop working suddenly, from time to time.

I have the two extensions installed locally:

[image]

When connected to a remote SSH, I see that they appear not to be installed on the remote server (which is, again, something new, as they were installed just yesterday)

[image]

When I click on the icon to install them on the remote server I get:

1. a pop-up screen on the bottom right corner:

[image]

2. Also on the log terminal I see:

```
[2022-07-07 14:52:48.576] [remoteagent] [info] Getting Manifest... ms-toolsai.jupyter
[2022-07-07 14:52:48.639] [remoteagent] [error] Failed to install extension. ms-toolsai.jupyter
[2022-07-07 14:52:48.639] [remoteagent] [error] Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)
```

which unfortunately is not all that informative.

I also tried to install via the small download/ cloud button on the left-hand side panel:

[image]

Yet it does not work either.

Does anyone know the background of this error/ why the extensions stopped working suddenly?  NB from yesterday to today (when the extensions stopped working), VS code was not upgraded. Does this look like a bug, so that a bug report should be filled to their github page?

Local OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, remote is CentOS Linux 8. VS code version is:

```
1.68.1
30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630
x64
```